# Am using Push() array was used am trying to use for select a list from drop down menu and post that list into a span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

#### HTML section

div to show the values

```
    <div class="lef rightCol n">
    <span class="para"> add-on Services(Optional)</span>
    <div class="new">
    <ul>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div
```

div that contain drop down

```
       <div class="rightCol n mar ">
        <span id="at1" class="spn">Click here to add add-on Services</span>
        <ul id="ad1" class="drpdwn">
          <li><input type="checkbox"  id="ck1" value="1"><a id="a1">Drop Shadows</a></                           
          li> 
          <li><input type="checkbox" id="ck2"   value="2"><a id="a2">Reflections</a> <         
          li>
          <li><input type="checkbox"  id="ck3"  value="6">General Spotting</a></li>   
          </ul>
```

I have tried this slide down while click

#### jQuery

slide down while click at1(Span)

this is the try for show on span on new div

here where should i use Push() most of them force me to use i don't know how and for what

```
         var ots = []; 
         $('#at1,#at2,#at3,#at4,#at5,#at6').click(function(){
         $(this).next('.drpdwn').stop().slideToggle();
  
           }),

 $('#ck1').click(function()
 {

  option=$('#a1').text();
  


 $('.new ul').append('<li><span id="span1" alt="1" ></span></li>');
  
  $('#span1').html(option).addClass('surr');  
   ots.push({id: 1});  
  
    }),
     $('#ck2').click(function()
 {

  option=$('#a2').text();
  


 $('.new ul').append('<li><span id="span2" alt="1" ></span></li>');
  
  $('#span1').html(option).addClass('surr');  
   ots.push({id: 2});  
  
    }),
```

now i moved some value to array ots while append now the question is how to retrieve the newly created span's alt atrribute using array..?am using like these its not working clearly

some function

```
   var f = $('.new span').length;
       ad=o;
      cs=o;      
             for(i=1;i<=f;i++)
             {
                  $.each(this.opt, function() {
                    $.each(this, function(name, value) {
                     cs=eval($( "#span"+value).attr("alt"));
                     console.log(name + '=' + value);
                     ad+=cs; 
                     console.log("ad: "+ad);  
                       })
                      })
                  
                  }
```

it shows ad as Nan and every time i click those id's it created like 1 then 1,2 then 1,2,3 like this help me out every time select check box it plays like this.!

Comment: It's late, but I don't see a push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**push method is used to add new item in an array**...so in your code push() was obivously used to push items to array(though i cannot find push methods in your question...so wouldn't be able to explain in your case)

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

ex:

```
var sports = ["soccer", "baseball"];
sports.push("football", "swimming");
```